# Выполнение PHP кода через определенное время

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Здравствуйте, есть задача, выполнить определенный скрипт через время, допустим 5 минут. А именно, ajax запрос. Я думал отправлять его сразу, и делать sleep(), но понял что этот вариант не самый лучший, так как все 5 минут, скрипт будет занимать память ОЗУ.

Подумал на счет варианта, отправить ajax запрос по SetTimeout, но дело в том что в это время пользователь может закрыть вкладку преждевременно, и получается тогда запрос уже  не отправится?

Подскажите что можно предпринять для реализации метода.

Comment: Используйте CRON (Планировщик заданий), в интернете куча примеров, можете вызвать работу PHP файла или команду

Comment: @Arsen я тоже думал про крон, но хотел бы узнать возможно ли выполнение этой задачи без него.

Comment: Ну вы сами же, исходя из логической цепочки, описали другие варианты, которые не оптимальны. ))) Думаю лучше CRON